# Switch statement is skipped after two iterations of while loop

Tags: c, arduino, switch-statement

I am writing a state machine for an Arduino project to parse an input string from Serial1 input. I have a switch statement in a while loop that advances the state:

```
  char * tok = strtok(instr, " \r\n"); //instr is the input string
  int state = 0;
  int targx = 0, targy = 0;

  while (tok)
  {
    // State machine:
    // 0: start parsing
    // 1: N2 command, parse prediction
    // 2: Correct prediction, parse targx
    // 3: Parse targy
    // 4: Target parsing complete
    // 1000: Wrong prediction / unknown command
    switch (state)
    {
      case 0:
        if (strcmp(tok, "N2") == 0) state = 1; 
        else if (strcmp(tok, "PANGAIN") == 0) state = 5;
        else if (strcmp(tok, "TILTGAIN") == 0) state = 7;
        else state = 1000;
        break;

      case 1:
          //Look for a person
          int i = strlen(tok) - 1;
          while(i >= 0 && tok[i] != ':') {i--;}

          if (i >= 0) tok[i] = '\0';
          Serial.print("Here's what it saw: ");
          Serial.print(tok);
          Serial.print("\n");
          if (strcmp(tok, "person") == 0) 
          {
            state = 2;
            Serial.println(state);
          }
          else state = 1000;

        break;

      case 2:
        Serial.println("Inside case 2");
        targx = atoi(tok);
        Serial.print("Targx = ");
        Serial.print(targx, DEC);
        Serial.println("");
        state = 3;
        break;

      case 3:
        targy = atoi(tok);
        Serial.print("Targy = ");
        Serial.print(targy, DEC);
        Serial.println("");
        state = 4;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    // Move to the next token:
    tok = strtok(0, " \r\n");
    Serial.println(tok);
  }
```

The problem I'm having so far is it will get to case 1 and correctly identify that "person" is in the token and set the state to 2 but on every iteration of the while loop after that, it just skips the switch statement entirely. Here's what the output looks like for one input string:

```
Input String: N2 person:66 -1297 -538 2431 1331

> person:66 
> Here's what it saw: person 
> 2
> -1297
> -538 
> 2431 
> 1331
```

Can anyone tell me why the switch statement is being bypassed entirely after case 1 is hit? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: For extra debugging, print out the state just before the switch statement & see if it is the value that you expect.

Comment: You don't show the declaration for `instr`, or how the input data gets entered in to it.  It is possible that `strtok` is overwriting `state` when it sets the nul character at the end of the `-1297` token.

Answer (score 3):

Your if else statement in case 1 is not correct. 
The first if should be like this

```
if (i >= 0) {tok[i] = '\0';}
```

You are missing the brackets.
And the else statement should also be included in brackets like this.

```
      if (strcmp(tok, "person") == 0) 
      {
        state = 2;
        Serial.println(state);
      }
      else 
      {
        state = 1000;
      }
```

Or if it is just one line of code like yours, you could write it in a separate line.

```
      if (strcmp(tok, "person") == 0) 
      {
        state = 2;
        Serial.println(state);
      }
      else 
        state = 1000;
```

Otherwise it will assign value 1000 to state, that's why the for loop would skip all the switch cases.

My English is not very good. Hope you understand it.

Comment: Although often considered to be good practice, it is not necessary to use brackets in control structures containing a single statement. `if (i >= 0) tok[i] = '\0';` is perfectly valid as far as the language is concerned. Writing it on a separate line without brackets is the same as the OP's code because in C whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: @FeiXiang well then you could probably post your own solution.